# Flags of varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, flag-varieties

I was wondering if there is a generalization of flags in the following way: Suppose you have a series of inclusions of affine varieties $V_1\hookrightarrow V_2\hookrightarrow\cdots\hookrightarrow V_n$ were each inclusion is a closed immersion. Do the set of all such "generalized flags" form a variety? Is this even something that has been studied?

Comment: Yes---look up "flag hilbert scheme."

Comment: This reminds me of higher adeles introduced by Beilinson and Parshin. You should be able to get some references by searching these keywords.

Comment: I doubt you can get a reasonable scheme in your affine setup. Rather, take everybody projective and fix the Hilbert polynomial of each $V_i$. Then you definitely get a subscheme of the product of a bunch of ordinary Hilbert schemes (which you should see as analogous to, and generalizing, Grassmannians).

Comment: @Allen: I completely agree with you, but probably there is also a "flag Haiman-Sturmfels scheme" if one is only interested in affine subschemes of a specific type that are stable with respect to a torus action (i.e., generalizing the notion of affine cones for the usual Hilbert scheme).